# Powershell - Unable to automatically pass credentials to gmail.com

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation

I'm trying to understand how to use powershell to automate IE navigation in general, and I found a sample script at http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/01/automated-web-forms.html

Here is the code:

```
function Login-GMail{ 
    param(
        [string]$uname,
        [string]$url="http://www.gmail.com",
        [bool]$cookie=$false 
    ) 

    $creds = get-credential $uname 
    $pass = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password 
    $ie=new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
    $ie.visible=$true 
    $ie.navigate($url) 

    while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4){start-sleep -m 100}

    $ie.document.getElementbyId("Email").value=$creds
    $ie.document.getElementbyId("Passwd").value=$pass 
    $ie.document.getElementbyName("PersistentCookie") | foreach {$_.checked=$cookie}
    $ie.document.getElementbyId("gaia_loginform").submit()

} 
Login-Gmail
```

The code looks perfectly fine but it does not work as expected

When I run this on a command line, i.e. C:\sandbox\gmail.ps1 me@gmail.com I get an error,

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'me@gmail.com'.
At line:1 char:3
+ cd <<<<  c:\sandbox\gmail.ps1 p...@gmail.com
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

When I run this in Powershell GUI and press the green arrow, a pop-up box asks for my username and password. However, when it opens gmail.com, it pre-populates the Username textbox with "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" and I get the following error

```
Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementbyName'.
At C:\sandbox\gmail.ps1:18 char:34
+     $ie.document.getElementbyName <<<< ("PersistentCookie") | foreach {$_.checked=$cookie}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementbyName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

How to troubleshoot this?

EDIT:

@ Goyuix

I made changes to the parameter list, added

```
Login-Gmail -uname me@gmail.com
```

and I removed

```
$creds=get-credential $uname
```

and get error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\sandbox\gmail.ps1:9 char:40
+     $pass = $creds.GetNetworkCredential <<<< ().Password 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetNetworkCredential:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

and

```
Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementbyName'.
At C:\sandbox\gmail.ps1:18 char:34
+     $ie.document.getElementbyName <<<< ("PersistentCookie") | foreach {$_.checked=$cookie}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementbyName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

If I remove

```
$ie.document.getElementbyName("PersistentCookie") | foreach {$_.checked=$cookie}
```

But include

```
$creds = get-credential $uname
```

Then a pop-up appears with the User name prepopulated with me@gmail.com. After I enter in the Password and press OK, the webpage with gmail appaers and the username is pre-populated with

System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

But here are no errors.

How to fix the code such that it automatically opens gmail and logs me into my account. Here is code so far:

```
function Login-GMail{ 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)][string]$uname,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)][string]$url="http://www.gmail.com",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)][bool]$cookie=$false 
    ) 

    $creds = get-credential $uname 
    $pass = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password 
    $ie=new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
    $ie.visible=$true 
    $ie.navigate($url) 

    while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4){start-sleep -m 100}

    $ie.document.getElementbyId("Email").value=$creds
    $ie.document.getElementbyId("Passwd").value=$pass 
    $ie.document.getElementbyId("gaia_loginform").submit()

} 
Login-Gmail -uname me@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error can be solved at least two different ways: Using a named parameter when invoking the `Login-Gmail` function or by decorating the `$uname` parameter with positional information:

Named Parameter:

```
Login-Gmail -uname me@gmail.com
```

Adding the positional information:

```
function Login-GMail{ 
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$uname,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
    [string]$url="http://www.gmail.com",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]
    [bool]$cookie=$false 
  )
```

Your second error regarding the `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` is that you are trying to assign the value of an object (the PSCredential) when the IE DOM expects a string. You can probably just omit the call to `get-credential` entirely and just assign the value present in the `$uname` variable.